# Change Stacked Widget index automatically after 5 seconds

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to display the first page of the stacked widget and after 3 seconds replace it by the second page automatically.

```
self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))
```

Code

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1316, 922)
    self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("testerener.png"))
    self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("teste.png"))
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("renner.png"))
     
    self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("renner.png"))
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    self.Pages.setCurrentIndex(1)

    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", " "))
    self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
    self.btn_home.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Imagem1"))
    self.btn_contato.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Imagem2"))
    self.btn_contato_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Imagem3"))
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sys
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  MainWindow.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: with this command below step 1 page how can I make a loop between the 3 pages
self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
QTimer.singleShot(3000, lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The same logic that applies but using a QTimer and calculating the following index:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTabWidget, QWidget


class TabManager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, tabwidget, interval=1000, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._interval = 0
        self._tabwidget = None
        self.timer = QTimer(timeout=self.handle_timeout)

        self.interval = interval
        self.tabwidget = tabwidget

    @property
    def interval(self):
        return self._interval

    @interval.setter
    def interval(self, dt):
        if self._interval == dt:
            return
        self.stop()
        self._interval = dt
        self.timer.setInterval(self._interval)
        self.start()

    @property
    def tabwidget(self):
        return self._tabwidget

    @tabwidget.setter
    def tabwidget(self, widget):
        self.stop()
        self._tabwidget = widget
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.stop()

    def handle_timeout(self):
        if self._tabwidget is None:
            return
        next_index = (self.tabwidget.currentIndex() + 1) % (self.tabwidget.count())
        self.tabwidget.setCurrentIndex(next_index)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    tabwidget = QTabWidget()
    tabwidget.resize(640, 480)
    tabwidget.show()

    for i in range(4):
        w = QWidget()
        tabwidget.addTab(w, f"tab-{i}")

    tabmanager = TabManager(tabwidget, 5 * 1000)
    tabmanager.start()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: i'm new to python i don't know how i can implement this, i just wanted to loop between pages

Comment: @Fernando I provide the general solution, I do not do the work of another user. Your job is to study and understand how to apply my solution (a complete demo) to your particular code. Here we do not do your homework but only solve the generic problem for the community. Bye

Comment: @Fernando Note: In SO it doesn't matter if you are a beginner or an expert in technology since we only focus on the problem, here the users are only intermediaries, they are not our objective. Therefore, the solution is based on the question and not on the user's level of knowledge: There are no answers for beginners or experts, there are only answers. Please read [ask] and review the [tour]